# What does here UserArray means?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

What does the below syntax represents?

```
typedef UserArray<T,W,L,H> MyType;
```

where:

- T = type of an array element
- W = width of an array element, 0 < W < 8
- L = low bound of array index (preferably zero)
- H = high bound of array index

Can anyone explain me using example for above declaration?

Does this concepts comes under STL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserArray` is a class template that takes four template parameters.

It's probably defined like that:

```
template<class T, int W, int L, int H> // parameter names might differ
class UserArray
{
    // ...
};
```

`typedef` is used to define aliases for types. This:

```
typedef UserArray<T,W,L,H> MyType;
```

Defines an alias for `UserArray` using the specified template parameters. `T` must be a type, and `W`, `L` and `H` must be compile-time integer constants. The resulting alias is called `MyType`, and using it is like using `UserArray` with the same parameters.

Those techniques are used to simplify typing when a type is used a lot in many places. For instance, you can do this:

```
typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;

IntVector vect; // a vector of ints
```

Comment: @Etienne: Does the example is related to Standard template library?

Comment: @Abhineet, your example is not related to the standard template library.

Answer (score 1):

`UserArray` should be a **container** `class template`, something like below:

```
template<typename TYPE, unsigned int SIZE, int LOWER_BOUND, int HIGHER_BOUND>
class UserArray {
//...
};
```

So if you declare it as,

```
typedef UserArray<int,100,0,99> MyType;
```

Which means `MyType` is an array of `100` `int`s; it's lower bound is `0` and higher bound is `99`. So the type should play within the range of `0` to `99`. However, I don't feel that Lower and Higher bound are needed; because array size states everything.